# How can i create resizable rectangle in java swing?

Tags: java, swing

I need to add a small feature in a project where, rectangle with some trimable text in it, and the rectangle should be resizable.

I'm short of time so didnt try out reading and working on it much.
I need some idea how to go for it.

Thanks in advance.

-Uday

Comment: Sounds like a JTextArea.  Could you be much more specific?

Comment: If the rectangle is resizable should it also be movable? If not, why not just use a JLabel, with a custom border and a LayoutManager setting which allows resizing?

Answer (score 2):

I got the following example from online only, I am not the owner of this code sample. I forgot it where did I get this. Anyway hope this would help you:

**Resizable.java**

---

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputListener;

// Resizable.java

public class Resizable extends JComponent {

  public Resizable(Component comp) {
    this(comp, new ResizableBorder(8));
  }

  public Resizable(Component comp, ResizableBorder border) {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(comp);
    addMouseListener(resizeListener);
    addMouseMotionListener(resizeListener);
    setBorder(border);
  }

  private void resize() {
      if (getParent() != null) {
        ((JComponent)getParent()).revalidate();
      }
  }

  MouseInputListener resizeListener = new MouseInputAdapter() {
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
      if (hasFocus()) {
          ResizableBorder border = (ResizableBorder)getBorder();
          setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(border.getCursor(me)));
      }
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
       setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
    }

    private int cursor;
    private Point startPos = null;

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
      ResizableBorder border = (ResizableBorder)getBorder();
      cursor = border.getCursor(me);
      startPos = me.getPoint();
      requestFocus();
      repaint();
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {

      if (startPos != null) {

        int x = getX();
        int y = getY();
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();

        int dx = me.getX() - startPos.x;
        int dy = me.getY() - startPos.y;

        switch (cursor) {
          case Cursor.N_RESIZE_CURSOR:
            if (!(h - dy < 50)) {
              setBounds(x, y + dy, w, h - dy);
              resize();
            }
            break;

          case Cursor.S_RESIZE_CURSOR:
            if (!(h + dy < 50)) {
              setBounds(x, y, w, h + dy);
              startPos = me.getPoint();
              resize();
            }
            break;

          case Cursor.W_RESIZE_CURSOR:
            if (!(w - dx < 50)) {
              setBounds(x + dx, y, w - dx, h);
              resize();
            }
            break;

          case Cursor.E_RESIZE_CURSOR:
            if (!(w + dx < 50)) {
              setBounds(x, y, w + dx, h);
              startPos = me.getPoint();
              resize();
            }
            break;

          case Cursor.NW_RESIZE_CURSOR:
            if (!(w - dx < 50) && !(h - dy < 50)) {
              setBounds(x + dx, y + dy, w - dx, h - dy);
              resize();
            }
            break;

          case Cursor.NE_RESIZE_CURSOR:
            if (!(w + dx < 50) && !(h - dy < 50)) {
              setBounds(x, y + dy, w + dx, h - dy);
              startPos = new Point(me.getX(), startPos.y);
              resize();
            }
            break;

          case Cursor.SW_RESIZE_CURSOR:
            if (!(w - dx < 50) && !(h + dy < 50)) {
              setBounds(x + dx, y, w - dx, h + dy);
              startPos = new Point(startPos.x, me.getY());
              resize();
            }
            break;

          case Cursor.SE_RESIZE_CURSOR:
            if (!(w + dx < 50) && !(h + dy < 50)) {
              setBounds(x, y, w + dx, h + dy);
              startPos = me.getPoint();
              resize();
            }
          break;

          case Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR:
            Rectangle bounds = getBounds();
            bounds.translate(dx, dy);
            setBounds(bounds);
            resize();
          }


          setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(cursor));
        }
     }

   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
     startPos = null;
    }
  };
}
```

**ResizableBorder.java**

---

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

// ResizableBorder.java

public class ResizableBorder implements Border {
  private int dist = 8;

  int locations[] =
  {
    SwingConstants.NORTH, SwingConstants.SOUTH, SwingConstants.WEST,
    SwingConstants.EAST, SwingConstants.NORTH_WEST,
    SwingConstants.NORTH_EAST, SwingConstants.SOUTH_WEST,
    SwingConstants.SOUTH_EAST
  };

  int cursors[] =
  {
    Cursor.N_RESIZE_CURSOR, Cursor.S_RESIZE_CURSOR, Cursor.W_RESIZE_CURSOR,
    Cursor.E_RESIZE_CURSOR, Cursor.NW_RESIZE_CURSOR, Cursor.NE_RESIZE_CURSOR,
    Cursor.SW_RESIZE_CURSOR, Cursor.SE_RESIZE_CURSOR
  };

  public ResizableBorder(int dist) {
    this.dist = dist;
  }

  public Insets getBorderInsets(Component component) {
      return new Insets(dist, dist, dist, dist);
  }

  public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
      return false;
  }

  public void paintBorder(Component component, Graphics g, int x, int y,
                          int w, int h) {
      g.setColor(Color.black);
      g.drawRect(x + dist / 2, y + dist / 2, w - dist, h - dist);

      if (component.hasFocus()) {


        for (int i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          Rectangle rect = getRectangle(x, y, w, h, locations[i]);
          g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
          g.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width - 1, rect.height - 1);
          g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
          g.drawRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width - 1, rect.height - 1);
        }
      }
  }

  private Rectangle getRectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h, int location) {
      switch (location) {
      case SwingConstants.NORTH:
          return new Rectangle(x + w / 2 - dist / 2, y, dist, dist);
      case SwingConstants.SOUTH:
          return new Rectangle(x + w / 2 - dist / 2, y + h - dist, dist,
                               dist);
      case SwingConstants.WEST:
          return new Rectangle(x, y + h / 2 - dist / 2, dist, dist);
      case SwingConstants.EAST:
          return new Rectangle(x + w - dist, y + h / 2 - dist / 2, dist,
                               dist);
      case SwingConstants.NORTH_WEST:
          return new Rectangle(x, y, dist, dist);
      case SwingConstants.NORTH_EAST:
          return new Rectangle(x + w - dist, y, dist, dist);
      case SwingConstants.SOUTH_WEST:
          return new Rectangle(x, y + h - dist, dist, dist);
      case SwingConstants.SOUTH_EAST:
          return new Rectangle(x + w - dist, y + h - dist, dist, dist);
      }
      return null;
  }

  public int getCursor(MouseEvent me) {
      Component c = me.getComponent();
      int w = c.getWidth();
      int h = c.getHeight();

      for (int i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          Rectangle rect = getRectangle(0, 0, w, h, locations[i]);
          if (rect.contains(me.getPoint()))
              return cursors[i];
      }

      return Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR;
  }
}
```

**Example Implementation:**  **ResizableComponent.java**

---

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;


    /* ResizableComponent.java */



 public class ResizableComponent extends JFrame {

      private JPanel panel = new JPanel(null);
      private Resizable resizer;


      public ResizableComponent() {

          add(panel);

          JPanel area = new JPanel();
          area.setBackground(Color.white);
          resizer = new Resizable(area);
          resizer.setBounds(50, 50, 200, 150);
          panel.add(resizer);


          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          setSize(new Dimension(350, 300));
          setTitle("Resizable Component");
          setLocationRelativeTo(null);

          addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {

              requestFocus();
              resizer.repaint();
            }
          });
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          ResizableComponent rc = new ResizableComponent();
          rc.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
```

**Updated: ResizeRectangle.java**

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ResizeRectangle extends JPanel {

    private int SIZE = 8;
    private Rectangle2D[] points = {new Rectangle2D.Double(50, 50, SIZE, SIZE), new Rectangle2D.Double(150, 100, SIZE, SIZE)};
    Rectangle2D s = new Rectangle2D.Double();
    ShapeResizeHandler ada = new ShapeResizeHandler();

    public ResizeRectangle() {
        addMouseListener(ada);
        addMouseMotionListener(ada);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            g2.fill(points[i]);
        }
        s.setRect(points[0].getCenterX(), points[0].getCenterY(),
                Math.abs(points[1].getCenterX() - points[0].getCenterX()),
                Math.abs(points[1].getCenterY() - points[0].getCenterY()));

        g2.draw(s);
    }

    class ShapeResizeHandler extends MouseAdapter {

        Rectangle2D r = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, SIZE, SIZE);
        private int pos = -1;

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
            Point p = event.getPoint();

            for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                if (points[i].contains(p)) {
                    pos = i;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
            pos = -1;
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
            if (pos == -1) {
                return;
            }

            points[pos].setRect(event.getPoint().x, event.getPoint().y, points[pos].getWidth(),
                    points[pos].getHeight());
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Resize Rectangle");

        frame.add(new ResizeRectangle());
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for ur time, actually i found and tried that code. I feel that is a code to resize a panel where 8 small rectangles are used. Let me know if get it right..

Comment: you can follow the sample code given right? (ResizableComponent.java) just follow and implement it something similar.

Comment: So,  I tried to pass Rectangle object instead of component, but seems tht will not work. And tht code has logic where a jPanel is being resized by putting 8 small rectangles on edges, which cannot be applied to a rectangle. There must be a easy way to do..

Comment: You want to resize your JPanel which should apply the effect on the 8 small rectangles as well right?

Comment: No. I just need to create a rectangle which can be resized.

Comment: You can get the source here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Resizeashape.htm

Comment: If you satisfied, please accept the answer in order to close this question and you may vote for this answer if you wish. Thanks

Comment: Ok.. before closing, I can build on to that code. but currently if i try to run that code I'm getting error on the line where mouseMotionListener is written!  Error is "The method addMouseMotionListener(MouseMotionListener) in the type Component is not applicable for the arguments (ResizeRectangle.ShapeResizeHandler)" Please have a look, its very strange, adding listeners is basic thing, why this error.

Comment: It is running fine in my system. Did you change anything with source? anyway I will update that answer, just try run that one. (no change)