# How to create a resizable rectangle in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I'm repeating same question, I need to create a rectangle which is re-sizable, in java swing.

How can i do this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Dude, what happened? yesterday I shared the source right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256222/how-can-i-create-resizable-rectangle-in-java-swing/4256298#4256298

Comment: Why don't you continue there? don't repeat the questions here. you can update the existing question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi ya buddy, 

I'm still trying on it, but not getting.
I tried to pass Rectangle object instead of component, but seems tht will not work. 
And tht code has logic where a jPanel is being resized by putting 8 small rectangles on edges, which cannot be applied to a rectangle. There must be a easy way to do..

Answer (score 0):

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 200);
r.grow(100, 100); // resize :)
```